# Android override predefined parent style

Tags: android, android-styles

I use one of the predefined styles for MaterialButton.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Approve" />
```

And this is the style predefined style which i used.

```
 </style>
    <style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/mtrl_btn_padding_left</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/mtrl_btn_padding_right</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/mtrl_btn_stroke_color_selector</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">@dimen/mtrl_btn_stroke_size</item>
  </style>
```

And this is parent style of `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton`

```
 <style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/mtrl_text_btn_text_color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/mtrl_btn_text_btn_padding_left</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/mtrl_btn_text_btn_padding_right</item>
    <item name="iconTint">@color/mtrl_text_btn_text_color_selector</item>
    <item name="iconPadding">@dimen/mtrl_btn_text_btn_icon_padding</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/mtrl_btn_text_btn_bg_color_selector</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/mtrl_btn_text_btn_ripple_color</item>
  </style>
```

Now i tried to override one of the attributes of `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton` in my styles.xml

```
 <style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
 </style>
```

I wonder whether this is the right approach or not to override a predefined style and will style `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton` use `@color/colorAccent` as text color. I think its working but i can not be sure is there any side effect of this approach or is there a better way ?

Comment: I'd suggest you to define your own style and inherit from the widget you need. 
<style name="MyTextButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">

Comment: But in that case i have to redefine all inherited styles. I want to use existing styles just with a few customization.

Comment: that's what it does, if you define a style with a parent, the defined style inherit everything from it. I know that you probably don't want to go and modify all the styles used by your elements, but it's the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the following:

```
<style name="MyCustomStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

```
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton.MyCustomStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

With these approach, you would inherit all the properties of your parent style and you would be declare only those properties that you like to change/override.

And use this style in your layout file as follow:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/MyCustomStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Approve" />
```

or

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton.MyCustomStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Approve" />
```

Comment: Could you please post your layout xml code and style xml code?

Comment: An addition to my answer, you need to use this custom style in your layout file:
```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/MyCustomStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Approve" />
```